# call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)

Tags: iot, rfid, nodemcu

I tried to do a RFID card reading  with the esp8266. But when I upload the code it's got an error. Can you help me? Here's a part of the code:

1. > void loop() {
   > // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
   > readsuccess = getid();

   ```
      if(readsuccess) {  
      digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
        HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient

        String UIDresultSend, postData;
        UIDresultSend = StrUID;

        //Post Data
        postData = "UIDresult=" + UIDresultSend;

        http.begin("http://IPaddress/NodeMCU_RC522_Mysql/getUID.php"); 

        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        int httpCode = http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
        String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload

        Serial.println(UIDresultSend);
        Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
        Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload

        http.end();  //Close connection
        delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: `WiFiClient client; http.begin(client, "http://IPaddress/NodeMCU_RC522_Mysql/getUID.php");`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, not that there is a new version, but that the devs removed the normal function with the comment "old API is now explicitly forbidden". To use nhe new Version you have to create and pass an empty "WiFiClient" Object now, like this:

```
String newImprovedHttpCall(String yourURL){
    HTTPClient myClient;
    {
        WiFiClient wificlient;
        myClient.begin(wificlient, url.c_str());
    }
    if (myClient.GET()>0) {
        String payload = http.getString();
        //Serial.println(payload);
        return payload;
    }else {
        Serial.print("Error code");
    }
    return "error";
}
```